# Does strcmp in C++ check every value in a string if the second parameter is "0"?

Tags: c++

If my string `input` is `1234567890`, and I do the following:

```
(strcmp(input,"0"))
```

Will that return `1` if there is a `0` in my character array of `1234567890` and 0 if there isn't?

I know I can test this, and I did, and the answer is yes, but I'm not sure why and I can't find absolute specifics on strcmp.

Comment: `strcmp` is a comparison function, not a search function. Perhaps look at the man page (also online, e.g. http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp)

Comment: I think you're confusing `strcmp()` and `strchr()`.  No: strcmp() will return "0" only if the strings are identical (in content and in width).  Otherwise, it return "-1" for less than, or 1 for greater than.

Comment: *I know I can test this, and I did, and the answer is yes* Really? You might want to rerun the test..

Answer (score 0):

No. `strcmp` returns 0 if the two strings are the same, non 0 otherwise.
Looks like you didn't even bother to google!

Comment: I'm asking because in a commented out piece of code it says "check if the string has 0", and the code was `else if (strcmp(input,"0")==0) { return value; } \\ check if the string has 0.` The string is `1234567890`.

Comment: @eveo: by "has 0" the comment must mean "has exactly the text '0'", not "contains 0 somewhere"... obviously an unfortunately ambiguous comment.

Comment: True, but I really don't see how that logic fits into the program at all, why specifically "0". that comment makes no sense from all perspectives, you'd never enter a 0 in this application.. dafuq

Answer (score 0):

No, it compares two strings.

`strcmp()` returns 0 only if both strings are the same. Otherwise, the return value says something about the first non-matching character.

In your case, this has to do with the comparison between '1' and your '0'. It makes no difference that the other string has a '0' at the end.

Answer (score 0):

`strcmp()` will typically check all characters from the first one until the last one or until there's a mismatch in the two strings.

The exact internal implementation of `strcmp()`, if you're asking about that, is not specified in the language standard. In theory, it could find lengths of the two strings and if they are equal, compare the strings using units bigger than `char` and even do that backwards.

`strcmp()` compares strings, not searches for one in the other. It returns 0 if the strings are identical. Otherwise it returns either a positive or a negative value, representing the sign of the difference between the first mismatching characters (the characters' values being treated as unsigned).

Answer (score 0):

> Does strcmp in C++ check every value in a string if the second
>   parameter is “0”

No it does not, `strcmp()` is a string compare function which checks if one string equals another. If it does, it returns `0` if one string is ordinally greater than the other, it returns `1` and returns `-1` otherwise.

To check if it *does* exist, I suggest you write your own function for this.

```
//return 1 if if the character exists, 0 otherwise
int DoesCharExist(const char *pData, char character)
{
   char *data = pData;
   while(*data++){
     if(*data == character) return 1;
   } 
   return 0;
}
```